# Prevent screen zoom on textbox focus on Windows Mobile 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, css, textinput

On Windows Mobile 7, when a user clicks on a text box before entering some data - the screen usually zooms in to the box and pulls up the keyboard.

Is there a way to prevent the zoom?  Or is this a setting on the phone itself?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks gents - but the answer I needed was to include a viewport meta tag that defined the 'user-scalable' parameter as 'no'.  Anyone grappling with mobile device cross browser compatibility issues should check this page out - a huge help to me today.

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens in the web browser as the textbox could be tiny when it is clicked. I agree it can be annoying. It does not happen in native apps however.

Answer (score 0):

if you click on a textbox in the app, and it is under the area where the keyboard would be.
It is normal behavior when text box is focused. Your content is moving up when on screen keyboard is appearing.

if you want your content to stay on it's place you can try to use Coding4fun controls(download with sample here: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). Run Test Application, go to Promts -> Basic input or Advanced input.